# How does pycuda run garbage collection?

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I am learning pycuda, but every time I finish running a programme, something still takes up some memory of GPU, how to clear memory of GPU, or how does pycuda run the gc?

Comment: How are you inspecting it? Are you sure its pycuda, and not just the OS or your internet browser?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as garbage collection in PyCUDA. If you want to free the memory used by an allocation, you have to explicitly free it yourself.

When a context is destroyed, all of the resources which were consumed by that context are freed. This process occurs at the GPU driver level and is transparent to the programmer.